# How can I put a square on a map that follows the pointer

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Exists a way to put a square on a map in openlayers 3 that follows the pointer and get its coordinates when I click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an [`ol.Overlay`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html) to follow the pointer. Take a look - http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/kyfs0w5e/

```
var square = new ol.Overlay({
    element: document.getElementById('square'),
    offset: [-10, -10],
    stopEvent: false
});
map.addOverlay(square);

map.on('pointermove', function(evt){
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    square.setPosition(coord);
});

map.on('click', function(evt){
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    console.info('You clicked: ', coord.join());
});
```

Comment: Thank you It works but is possible get the four coordinates of the square?

Comment: There's only the pointer coordinate, the square is only a 20x20 px. You can also use screen coordinate, it is `evt.pixel`.

Comment: Ok but for example if I have to get the current coordinates of the square in the map how I can do it? Because the real problem is for the zoom

Comment: The square coordinate is the same of the pointer: `evt.coordinate`

Comment: Ok I understand this but I need the coordinates of the vertices. Can i get these?

Comment: I don't understand your use case, the square is not a `geometry`, it's just an `ol.Overlay/HTML-div`. So, no, it's not possible in this approach.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In my case I have to create a rubber in openlayer and I need to get the coordinates to check if there is a intersection. How can I do this?

Comment: Would you please create a fiddle with your code so I can help you better?

Comment: Yes but for now I don't have a code is a simple function that I have to create.

Comment: But exist a way to get the corrispondence value of 1cm?? in a map? for example 1cm=10km